# How to align image with a title and heading on the same line, like the experience column on linkedIn

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

[image]

I'd like to create a command that takes 3 arguments, icon path, title and company and renders the result like LinkedIn.
Ideally the height of the text should be automatically calculator based on image height

Current solution

```
\newcommand{\CompanyEntry}[6]{
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{@{}m{#2}@{\hspace{10pt}}l@{\hspace{10pt}}r@{}}
    \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=#2,height=#2,keepaspectratio]{#1}} &
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      \textbf{#3} \\ #4 \\
    \end{tabular} &
    % \hspace{11cm}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}}
      #5 \\ #6 \\
    \end{tabular} \\
  \end{tabular}
  \vspace{5pt}
}
```

The problem with this is the date and location is not right aligned

Comment: What‘s your current approach, as code?

Comment: updated in the description, the problem is time is not right aligned

Comment: Welcome! Can you provide code we can compile to reproduce the problem? I can't even guess what the relationship is between the fragment you posted and either the image you show or any date/time.

Comment: You really should comment your macro arguments, for your sake as well as ours.  Anyway you centered the image but used [t] instead of [c] for both tabulars.